# How to enable HP Pavilion tx1000 touch screen?

Tags: upgrade, 10.10, multi-touch, hp-pavilion

After I upgrade from ubuntu 10.04 to ubuntu 10.10, I cannot used my touchscreen anymore?

What steps can I take to get it working again?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to enable this touchscreen under Maverick, see this comment:
https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/utouch/+bug/512188/comments/25

Please mark the above bug as affecting you too.